# C loop, beginner stuff

Tags: c, loops

I have a task to make a program in which you have to input a given number on a given position in another given number. Example: input:12345, 2, 3 output 123245. I tried to make a loop but it is apparently an infinite loop. The code is here:

```
int c, x, p, broj, i = 0, brcifara = 0, k, broj2, k2, broj3, ind;
printf("Unesite redom x, p i c: ");
scanf("%d%d%d", &x, &p, &c);
broj2 = x;
while(broj2 >= 1)
{
    broj2/= 10;
    brcifara += 1;
}
while(i < brcifara)
{
    k2 = pow(10, i + 1);
    k = broj3%k2;
    broj3 -= k*pow(10, i+ 1);

    if(i<p)
    {
        broj += k*pow(10, i+1);
    }
    if(i=p)
    {
        broj += c*pow(10, p);
    }
    if(i>p)
    {
        broj += k*pow(10, i+2);
    }
    i = i + 1;
}
printf("Broj je sada %d", broj);
```

}
C represents the number for putting in, X is the number in which we are putting C, P represents the postion(starting from 0). Brcifara is the number of digits. The problem is only in the second loop.

Comment: do not use pow in the integer programs

Comment: You change value of `i` in `if(i=p)`. Correct syntax is `if (i==p)`

Comment: Thanks man, should have thought of that before. You have saved me.

Comment: What does the `2, 3` mean in `12345, 2, 3`? (insert `2` after `3`?)

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin it means that the number is being put on a second place after the last number (right to left)

Comment: Why read the input as an integer, when reading as a string and character and then inserting the character in the string would be trivial? Then simply convert the resulting string to an integer value if needed.

Answer (score 0):

Why not trying something like that :

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdint.h>

#define MAX_STR_SIZE (100U)

int main()
{
  char x[MAX_STR_SIZE] = {'\0'};
  unsigned int p;
  char c;
  int x_int;
  printf("input x, p, c\n");
  scanf("%s %d %c", x, &p, &c);

  if(strlen(x) > p) // check string upper boundary
  {
    x[p] = c;
  }

  x_int = atoi(x);
  printf("%d\n", x_int);
}
```

X is a string in which you replace your C character at the given P position.
Thus :

- X is a string.
- C a character.
- P an index (unsigned char).

Then convert the X string to an integer using the atoi() function.

Comment: sry i need integers, if i can do it over this pls explain how do i translate to ints

Comment: just use the atoi() function to convert string to integer. I edited my answer